# how to send files over the network in java?

Tags: java, io, client-server

I have tried to send a file using the Java I / O
Now I'm trying to send a file over a network or to another computer.

I demonstrated, I want to send to the following address:

> \\192.168.1.1\tes\Report\

and I try to apply it the same as the Java I / O

> C://192.168.1.1/tes/Report/

and I try to apply it the same as the Java I / O.
I tried to run my program, and get the following error message results:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\192.168.1.1\tes\Report\Tes.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
>
> at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
>
> at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:179)

So, how do I send that file and what syntax do I need?

Comment: Why don't you use some FTP library?

Comment: Can you post a code snippet?

Comment: Hi Eran, I'm trying to use FTP, but there are some obstacles that I face, not on the FTP connection is needed to address + username and password from the address that we want to use, is not it?